# What configuration option(s) are available for disabling report generation in Karate?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to execute karate testing in an AWS Lambda. The lambda is failing because there's no filesystem to write the karate-reports. I've tried disabling the reporting using a number of different configuration options. Is this even possible?

**karate-config.js Examples:**

```
karate.configure('report', { enabled: false });
karate.callSingle('classpath:com/intuit/karate/execution-noop.feature');
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the output directory to /tmp/? You can do that with karate.outputDirectory and karate.env. AWS has a writeable area for such things.

Comment: @Fata1Err0r I haven't but will. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are on the latest version of Karate.

This use-case is important, so if you can provide the code and instructions to replicate this, we will fix it ASAP. I thought we were already gracefully failing if the report data is not being written, but we can certainly improve things.